# Where is the InfluxDB 2.0.2's config file path?

Tags: influxdb-2

I installed influxdb on my CentOS 8 by a script provided for [there: RedHat & CentOS](https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/).

after I installed it, I don't know which is its config file.
this is the result of my search.

```
[root@dele ~]# find / -name influx*
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/influxdb.service
/etc/systemd/system/influxd.service
/etc/logrotate.d/influxdb
/etc/default/influxdb
/root/.influxdbv2/influxd.bolt
/var/lib/influxdb
/var/log/influxdb
/usr/bin/influx
/usr/bin/influxd
/usr/lib/systemd/system/influxdb.service
/usr/lib/influxdb
/usr/lib/influxdb/scripts/influxdb.service
/opt/src/influxdb-2.0.2.x86_64.rpm
```

I guess it be `/etc/default/influxdb`, but I `cat` it get nothing but a empty file.

Comment: In my case ( version 2.7 ) it's under `/etc/influxdb/config.toml`

Answer (score 5):

There is a big change from v1 to v2 in InfluxDB,

in InfluxDB v1, the influxdb has configure file indeed, which locate there by default:

```
/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

but from v2, there have changed the config way. you can confirm it in [there](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/).

> When influxd starts, it checks for a file named config.* in the current working directory. The file extension depends on the syntax of the configuration file.

> To customize the directory path of the configuration file, set the INFLUXD_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to your custom path.

> On startup, influxd will check for a config.* in the INFLUXD_CONFIG_PATH directory.

So, in v2, the config file is vary by your start influxd place. If you want to have a special path, you should set `INFLUXD_CONFIG_PATH`.

Comment: In my case: /etc/influxdb/